# Read folder number in ascending order in python

Tags: python

I want to read folder names in ascending order. But somehow, my code didn't read in ascending order even I have used sort(). And in result, it shows weird order. Is there a way to fix this?

## My code

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_path):
    dirs.sort()
    print(os.path.basename(root))
```

## My folder names

[image]

## The output from my code

```
0
1
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
2
20
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

## What I want

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
```

Comment: You can convert the dir names to type `int` instead of type `str` or you can use `'my-string'.zfill(n)` to add n leading zeros to your dir names.

Comment: Heres my complicated solution to this: Add the stripped down names of all the files(assuming they are all numbers) to an array, then convert the elements in this array to numbers, then sort the array smallest to greatest and then finally use the organized array to iterate through all of the files

Comment: Is this folder name always numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your directory name always numbers, use this code:

use **dirs.sort(key=int)**;

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_path):
    dirs.sort(key=int)
    print(os.path.basename(root))
```

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the greatest solution but its what I thought of at the time haha:

```
# Array of all of the folder names not necessarily in order
folder_names =['4', '1', '0', '10', '9', '5', '11', '3', '7', '6', '2', '8']

# Convert all elements to ints and then sort it smallest to largest
organized_array = sorted([int(name) for name in folder_names])
```